# play/pause of spotify disappeared from sound menu on menu bar

Tags: 20.04, unity, sound, spotify, menu-bar

Up to later last year, I could control play/pause/skip and see now playing from the volume menu on the right side of the menu bar.

It suddenly disappeared after updating spotify to

`1.1.77.643.g3c4c6fc6        57     latest/stable (snap version)`

Does anyone know how to fix this/does anyone suffer from the same symptom?

I use `Ubuntu 20.04` with `unity`
(Please don't comment on why I don't use gnome or things related to that.)

Comment: Have you tried to use Spotify from [web](http://open.spotify.com) ??

Comment: The feature doesn't work from web version either